# Running sonarqube in Docker keeps redirecting me back to login page

Tags: redirect, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I've had SonarQube running for a good while but haven't used it very much but in general stuff seems to have been working. I'm running it inside Docker.

I just updated it to LTS (6.7) and after that it seems to have gone into some limbo state. I'm able to log in and browse the website but as soon as I try to perform some operation (seems to not matter what that operation is), I get redirected to the login page. If I log in again, everything repeats. So I'm unable to actually perform any action it seems.

At first I thought this had to have something to do with old data conflicting with the new setup. So I cleaned everything out and set it up from scratch. The problem remains, I'm unable to do anything and get redirected to the login page every time.

For example, after the clean setup, I log in with admin/admin and I get the "first time tutorial" where I'm offered to create a token. I tried to do that but get directed to the login page. I log in again and this time I try to skip the tutorial but then I get redirected to the login page. Below is a part of the access.log for when I try to skip the tutorial:

```
10.3.1.119 - - [16/Nov/2017:00:12:48 +0000] "POST /gor-sq/api/users/skip_onboarding_tutorial HTTP/1.0" 401 - "https://build.acme.com/gor-sq/projects" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" "AV/CJhNZndR3RsZuAAA4"
10.3.1.119 - - [16/Nov/2017:00:12:48 +0000] "GET /gor-sq/api/users/identity_providers HTTP/1.0" 200 24 "https://build.acme.com/gor-sq/sessions/new?return_to=%2Fgor-sq%2Fprojects" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" "AV/CJhNZndR3RsZuAAA5"
10.3.1.119 - - [16/Nov/2017:00:12:48 +0000] "GET /gor-sq/api/navigation/global HTTP/1.0" 200 573 "https://build.acme.com/gor-sq/sessions/new?return_to=%2Fgor-sq%2Fprojects" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" "AV/CJhNZndR3RsZuAAA6"
```

The first line indicates that the POST is getting a 401 response. Without being absolutely certain, it does look like it's the POST operations that are getting 401 responses while GET works.

This setup does sit behind a reverse proxy but as I said before, the setup has been working fine before and no changes have been made to the reverse proxy setup.

Comment: Did you check/compair the SonarQube configuration file?

Comment: @JeroenHeier as I said, the second time I installed I did a completely fresh install so the config file was the one shipped with SonarQube. However, I did try running sonarqube completely standalone (ran `docker run sonarqube` on my laptop and that came up and behaves just fine. So this must have something to do with my specific setup.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I am not so late. I had the same issue. What worked for me is the deleting cookies from the browser and everything else works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
https://myserver.com/sonar/api/users/skip_onboarding_tutorial
I got 401 and I was redirected to the Login page. I looked at the source code and request.ts was erroring out at line 108.

```
submit(): Promise<Response> {
const { url, options } = this.getSubmitData({ ...getCSRFToken() });
return window.fetch((window as any).baseUrl + url, options);}
```

Looked like an issue with the CSRFToken. Since I have Sonarqube running behind a Nginx Reverse Proxy, there might have been something to do with the way I was handling the cookies.

So when I looked a little bit, I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47909810/3221249

Basically, they changed the way you handle secure cookies after v6.0. Since I was making the cookie secure and httponly to true(not letting the client browser interact with the js code) I was having the above issue. I was doing this even before my non-ssl traffic hits Nginx. I have another proxy server running HAProxy which was handling this so I commented that part of the definitions.

```
#rspirep ^(Set-cookie:.*) \1;\ Secure if ! secure
#rspirep ^(Set-cookie:.*) \1;\ httponly
```

I hope this helps you.